"to" keyword is not working while sending email
I'm trying to send an email in Laravel, but I'm encountering an issue when using the to keyword in the email. The email doesn't send as expected, and I suspect it's because to is a reserved keyword in PHP.  How can I properly send an email using the to keyword in Laravel without it causing any issue
class ProgressReportMailTest extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $to;
    public $emailBody;

 
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->to = $data['to'];
       
        $this->emailBody = $data['emailbody'] ?? null;

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
      
        return $this->view('your view');
    }
}


What makes you think to is a reserved keyword in PHP?

In Laravel, the to property is  reserved/used in certain contexts, which can cause issues when using it directly in email functionality, especially when sending emails.
To avoid conflicts with the reserved to keyword, it's recommended to use the ->to() method in Laravel's Mailable class.
The to() method allows you to specify the recipient's email address without conflicting with the reserved keyword.
